# How the optical CD disc gets drawn in when we gently push it? what is the mechanism behind it?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, optical-materials

We have seen CD drives that have slits. The CD gets drawn inside upon a gentle
push. how the CD gets drawn inside upon a gentle push? How it's mechanism works?

[image: optical CD disc]

Comment: There’s a motor that pulls it in. But this is an engineering question, not physics.

Comment: @The Photon sir, thanks